# Printing spark dstream on Amazon EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, spark-streaming, amazon-emr

I am submitting the spark streaming job on Amazon EMR using step API. Everything works fine as I get the output in Amazon S3. However, I would like to know when does the file streaming ends so I have added a print statement. I dont know where can I see the output of print statement.

OR

Please suggest if there is a way to find out the file streaming has been completed.

thanks

Code:

```
object CustomReceiver {
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))
ssc.checkpoint("s3://checkpointforstreaming/")
val lines = ssc.textFileStream("s3://incomingstreamingdata/")
val kvPairs = lines.flatMap(retAtrTuple)
kvPairs.print() // Probably this statment works but I dont know where to see the output.

kvPairs.repartition(1).saveAsTextFiles("s3://outputstreaming/sc") // this statement works
}
Function (retAtrTuple) splits lines to words
```

Comment: This depends upon where in your code you put your print statement. Would you be able to share a code snippet?

Comment: @JonathanKelly I have added the code snippet.  I am creating a cluster using   the console available on the browser. Shall I use the command prompt (Windows) or terminal(linux) for creating cluster ?  .thanks for you response